# How to run lint for all product flavours in one command - Android?

Tags: java, android, static-analysis, lint, android-productflavors

I have implemented the product flavors for my project. I am building three new application in the same codebase.

After gradle sync, three different flavors have been generated, say **flavor1Debug**, **flavor1Release**, **flavor2Debug**, **flavor2Release**.

I have moved all flavor specific resources inside the flavor specific res folder. When I tried to run **./gradlew lintRelease**(which is supposed to run lint for **flavor1Release** and **flavor2Release**), it's not detecting any of the errors

For testing the lint, I have introduced an unused resource inside the **res** folder of **flavor1** and **flavor2**. I tried to run **./gradlew lintFlavor1Release** or **./gradlew lintFlavor2Release**, its detecting the error and throwing respectively.

But **./gradlew lintRelease** is not throwing any errors. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Make a custom task that will run the necessary flavor-dependant lint tasks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

make a custom gradle task that will run all those lint tasks separately.

```
tasks.register("runAllLinters")

afterEvaluate {

    if ("lintFlavor1Release" in tasks.names) {
        runAllLinters.dependsOn tasks.named("lintFlavor1Release")
    }
}
```

of course, this will trigger only for Flavor1 - so you will need to expand both the `if()` condition, and the `runAllLinters.dependsOn` block to depend on ALL flavour-dependant lint tasks.

and finally, you should be able to run it like `./gradlew runAllLinters`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    def LINT_TASK_NAME = "lint"
    def lintTask = tasks.findByName(LINT_TASK_NAME)
    tasks.findAll { task ->
        task.name.startsWith(LINT_TASK_NAME) &&
                task.name != LINT_TASK_NAME &&
                // remove some standard lint subtasks
                !task.name.startsWith("lintFix") &&
                !task.name.startsWith("lintAnalyze")
    }.each { task -> lintTask.dependsOn.add(task) }
}
```

This makes task 'lint' to depend on all the other "lintXxxx" tasks except some standard.